subprocess error when installing PyFMI on Google Colab
I'm new to Google Colab and Python, but I'm trying to use Google Colab to run some tests to have an executable to load and run a FMU I did on OpenModelica.
I'm using Google Colab as I thought it would be easier.
However, I get an error whnen when trying to install PyFMI

> . !pip install pyfmi

> Collecting pyfmi
  Downloading PyFMI-2.5.tar.gz (4.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.8/4.8 MB 41.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


Any idea on why this is happening and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

You'd need to show more output – that's missing the crucial stuff (the error messages). If they're not visible, that'd complicate things...

Ah, actually: the last version of PyFMI has been released in 2018, so chances are it's not compatible with modern Python versions. Additionally, the binary wheels are only for Pythons 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6: https://pypi.org/project/PyFMI/#files

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@AKX Thank you. I didn't get anymore information other than the one I provided, which I understand it makes the solving more difficult. If not compatible with modern Python versions, do you have any idea how to solve it? Also, I was actually wondering if it might actually be a Google Colab problem and if it would be better to try another route...

The last version of PyFMI on PyPI has been released in 2018, and only has wheels for Pythons 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6.
However, it looks like development is still active on GitHub, and there are new versions of these packages, pre-compiled. They just aren't able to update it on PyPI right now.
If your Colab environment is running Python 3.8, you should be able to install these versions of the packages with
pip install https://github.com/modelon-community/Assimulo/releases/download/Assimulo-3.4.3/Assimulo-3.4.3-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
pip install https://github.com/modelon-community/PyFMI/releases/download/PyFMI-2.11.0/PyFMI-2.11.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl

